# Cleaning API Controllers by separating Swagger from the controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, module, swagger, controllers

I'm using Swagger as a UI for my rails API. That means that in my API controllers, I have a lot of swagger blocs of code, making my files hard and heavy to read.
I'm looking for a way to separate concerns.

This is what I had:

**In my controllers/api/v1/stuffs_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class StuffsController < BaseController
      has_scope :by_category, type: :array
      has_scope :by_stuff_type, type: :array
      has_scope :by_device_type, type: :array
      before_action :set_stuff, only: [:show, :like, :unlike, :desire, :undesire]

      swagger_controller :stuffs, 'Stuffs'    

      swagger_api :index do
        summary 'Get all the stuffs'
        param :query, :by_category, :string, :optionnal, "Category"
        param :query, :by_stuff_type, :string, :optionnal, "Stuff Type"
        param :query, :by_device_type, :string, :optionnal, "Device Type"
        param :query, :s, :array, :optionnal, "Search Terms"
      end

      def index
        render json: collection, each_serializer: Api::V1::Stuff::IndexSerializer, include: ['categories', 'users.devices', 'stuffs.categories', 'user', 'user.devices.device_model'], status: 200, root: nil
      end

    end
  end
end
```

And it's like that for every action in every controller :s

I tried creating modules to encapsulate Swagger UI logic and clean up a little bit my controllers. This is what I came up with (that doesn't work):

**In controllers/api/v1/stuffs_controller.rb:**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class StuffsController < BaseController
      include SwaggerStuffs

      has_scope :by_category, type: :array
      has_scope :by_stuff_type, type: :array
      has_scope :by_device_type, type: :array
      before_action :set_stuff, only: [:show, :like, :unlike, :desire, :undesire]

      swagger_controller :stuffs, 'Stuffs'    

      SwaggerStuffs.call_index
      def index
        render json: collection, each_serializer: Api::V1::Stuff::IndexSerializer, include: ['categories', 'users.devices', 'stuffs.categories', 'user', 'user.devices.device_model'], status: 200, root: nil
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**Then in lib/swagger_modules/recipes_controller_module.rb:**

```
module SwaggerStuffs
  def self.call_index
    swagger_api :index do
      summary 'Get all the stuffs'
      param :query, :by_category, :string, :optionnal, "Category"
      param :query, :by_stuff_type, :string, :optionnal, "Stuff Type"
      param :query, :by_device_type, :string, :optionnal, "Device Type"
      param :query, :s, :array, :optionnal, "Search Terms"
    end
  end
end
```

This produces the following error when I try to use swagger UI or restart the server:

```
uninitialized constant Api::V1::StuffsController::SwaggerStuffs (NameError)
```

I added `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in my **config/application.rb** file, but the same error appears.

Is there something I am missing ?
Is it a good practice to separate swagger logic from my controllers ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same issue. This is all I could find (the last comment gets to the point): https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs/issues/113